# Debugging Composer Transaction processor?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I've no clue how can I debug the transaction processor in hyperledger composer ..

I did the steps below but there is nothing is showing up:

- Start fabric network
- Create connection profile
- Develop sample application (model.cto, permission.acl, transaction processor or logic.js)
- Create business network archive file (.bna)
- Deploy .bna file on hyperledger fabric
- Finally create the rest server and run our example

But sometimes during testing our contract we need to see some logs related to the contract execution. So we can find if there are any logical issues with the contract. I tried to check  `docker logs contract_container_id`  but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer here -> [Debugging Transaction Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42622281/debugging-transaction-code)

The correct link in the example is
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/carauction-network/test/CarAuction.js#L31-L49

can use console.log() as normal for messages etc.

See also:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/problems/diagnostics

Comment: Thanks Paul, but actually console.log() is not working. Anyway, I'll try the part of diagnostic, I think this will gonna work.